# List comprehension and type problems (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, types, primes

I have annoying syntax error in following construction:

```
isPrime n = if numOfDivisors n == 0 then True else False            
    where numOfDivisors n = length $ [x | x <- [2..ceiling (sqrt n)], n `mod` x == 0]
```

How I can fix it? I'm new to Haskell, so I don't know what's wrong in `[2..ceiling (sqrt n)]`.

Thanks (sorry for my poor brain).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Troubles with truncate :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739598/troubles-with-truncate-realfrac-a-integral-b-a-b)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using both `sqrt` and `mod` with `n`--the first requires a floating point type, the latter requires an integral type. You probably want the latter, and to use `sqrt (fromIntegral n)` instead.

Some other unsolicited advice:

- There is no possible reason to do `if foo then True else False`. Just use the boolean expression alone.
- Function arguments are in scope in the `where` clause, so `numOfDivisors` doesdn't need `n` as an argument.
- Don't use `length` to check if a list is empty. Use `null` on the list of divisors instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped! One more question: how I can check whether `n <- [2..]`?

Comment: @vortexxx192: Check what? Not sure what you mean. `n <- [2..]` in a list comprehension means `n` will count up from 2, there's no filter or checking there...